# How to send a selected Value from a dropdownlist to a controller using MVC, Jquery and Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to get the selected value from a dropdown using jquery. Then i want to send this selected value to an Action Result Method in my controller possibly using Ajax call . As i am pretty new at this i'm not so sure on how i would achieve this.
so i have got an Action Method like this in my Controller ...

```
public ActionResult GetVehiclePart(string id)
{
    //i did like to send the selected value to this controller and filter data  like below
    var _partNumber = _catalogue.CatalogueData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Partnumber == id && x.Veh_ID == selectedValue);
    return PartialView("_Vehicle", _partNumber)
}
```

And in my script file`

```
//getting the value using jquery
var vehicle = $("#ModelResult").val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '../../VehiclesController/GetVehiclePart/' + vehicle,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        vehicle = $("#ModelResult").val();
        console.log(vehicle); // the value is printing here not sure how to post it to the controller
    },
    async: false
});
```

I may be doing something wrong here but if someone would help on how to achieve

Comment: I suggest dont use async false

Comment: So should i set it to true? if so.. what do i have to do to receive the selected value in my controller?

Comment: you know what you are doing wrong you are venturing like a foreigner in a new country without a map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your url is incorrect (unless you really have a controller named `VehiclesControllerController`), as is the `dataType` option. Change you ajax call to

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '@Url.Action("GetVehiclePart", "Vehicles")', // don't hard code your urls
    data: { id: $("#ModelResult").val() }, // pass the value to the id parameter
    dataType: 'html', // your returning a view, not json
    success: function(data) {
        // do something with the partial view you return?
        $(someElement).html(data);
    });
});
```

Side note: The query in your controller method is filtering data based on both an `id` value and `selectedValue`. Its unclear what `selectedValue` is referring to. If you want to pass 2 values to the controller then you can use

```
data: { id: $("#ModelResult").val(), selectedValue: anotherValue },
```

and change your method to

```
public ActionResult GetVehiclePart(string id, string selectedValue)
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense.. but what if i wanted to pass the value as a 2nd parameter? is his possible?

Comment: Have you seen the edit? Its not clear what values you actually want to pass, but you can pass as many as you want.

Comment: This did indeed help in figuring things out .. Thank you